# I want to trigger an event when one clicks on the content pane of an accordion in dojo

Tags: accordion, dojo

### Here is my code. I tried using script=dojo/connect but it does not work. My dojo version is 1.6.

```
<div dojoType="dijit.layout.AccordionContainer" style="height: 500px;">
<div dojoType="dijit.layout.ContentPane" title="Total Enrollment" id="TotalEnrollDiv"  selected="false" name="abc" dojoAttachEvent="ondijitclick:_onButtonClick">
<ul>
  <li><a href="#"  id="TEState" onclick="attention(id);"> Michigan </a> </li>
  <li><a href="#"  id="TESE" onclick="attention(id);"> SouthEast MI </a> </li>
  <li><a href="#"  id="TEStateChange" onclick="attention(id);"> MI Change</a></li>
  <li><a href="#"  id="TESEChange" onclick="attention(id);">SE MI Change</a></li>                                     
 </ul>
```

### This is where I used the script tag

```
 <script type="dojo/connect"> 
    var myDiv= dijit.byId("TotalEnrollDiv");
    this.connect(this,"onclick",function(evt){
    alert("myDivVal");
    });

 </script>
 </div>

  <div dojoType="dijit.layout.ContentPane" title="UnderGrad. Enrollment" selected="true" id="UGEnroll">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#"  id="UGState" onclick="attention(id);">Michigan </a> </li>
    <li><a href="#"  id="UGSE" onclick="attention(id);"> SouthEast MI  </a> </li>
    <li><a href="#"  id="UGStateChange" onclick="attention(id);"> MI Change </a></li>
     <li><a href="#"  id="UGSEChange" onclick="attention(id);">SE MI Change </a></li>
   </ul>
 </div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try putting the dojo/connect element inside the ContentPane, and add an event attribute. Everything inside that script element will then be executed when the ContentPane is clicked.

```
<div dojoType="dijit.layout.ContentPane" title="UnderGrad. Enrollment" selected="true" id="UGEnroll">

    <script type="dojo/connect" event="onClick">
        alert("abc");                     
    </script>

    <ul>
        <li><a href="#"  id="UGState" onclick="attention(id);">Michigan </a> </li>
        <li><a href="#"  id="UGSE" onclick="attention(id);"> SouthEast MI  </a> </li>
        <li><a href="#"  id="UGStateChange" onclick="attention(id);"> MI Change </a></li>
        <li><a href="#"  id="UGSEChange" onclick="attention(id);">SE MI Change </a></li> 
    </ul>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure, but i guess this could work:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
       dojo.connect(dijit.byId('UGEnroll'), 'onClick', function(arg) {
          alert("myDivVal");
       });
    </script>
```